# Is it right to send PHP and Apache version in user agent string for an API?

Tags: php, apache, api, curl, user-agent

I have built an API framework that includes a lot of communication-related options, including input validations and encryptions.

I figured that building an 'API Wrapper' class would be required because of all those options, to simplify the process when another system wants to connect to my API. So they can basically download a single class and very easily connect to my system through that class from their system.

This wrapper class makes requests using cURL.

My system also includes a logger that tracks API calls for future reference and investigation (if problems appear as well as performance grading), including tracking user agent string for all of those requests.

My question is, how good or bad is it if I include Apache and PHP version numbers in that string alongside with the API wrapper class version, like this:

```
myApi/1.0 (Apache 2.2.17;PHP 5.4.0)
```

I am worried if it is a problem if PHP version number is transmitted over the web in such a way, even though it's between servers and not between client computer and server?

Comment: Will your service be hosted on multiple versions of PHP/Apache at the same time? If not, I would update the API version number anytime you move it to a new system.  They don't need to know your server info, can't change it, and probably can't adjust for it, so if it's only for your benefit, I'd avoid it. And yes, knowing the version of PHP or Apache (or WordPress, for that matter) is a risk, as every version has known bugs/vulnerabilities.

Comment: As Anthony said, it is a good practice for security measures to hide server details from end user.

Comment: Well the benefit is for developers who develop on that framework, since it gives better feedback on API performance. But I guess you both are right, I'd rather not sacrifice server security for better performance feedback for developer and just leave API wrapper version number in there.

Comment: It's not really a problem but why would you need this? I don't see any benefit of letting the world know what server and what php version you using. Some people even hiding the fact that they using php for their website. The problem is if a serious security flaw is found in certain php version, you don't want everyone to know that your server is using that version.

Comment: I understand why PHP version should not be publicly known. It would never be seen by anyone who visits the website, server (that uses API wrapper) is what would transmit the PHP version number to another server (that has the API). My question was really about how secure would it be for server-to-server transmission.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be crossing up the distinction between API and client. To paraphrase your question, it sounds like you've built:

1. an API with various services/resources
2. a client class (the "wrapper") that a third-party developer can use in her own application to communicate with your API

If that's the case, then the server information you're looking to convey is the system requirements for an application that will use your client class. That has no relationship to the version of PHP that your API runs on, except that you happened to develop both API and client on the same platform. For example, if you had built the API in PHP and the wrapper in Java, then it would be easier to see the distinction.

The minimum PHP version for the client/wrapper class is important information to convey to third-party developers, so that they can use the class as you intend. In that case, then yes, you should provide it somewhere (my suggestion would be in the documentation for the wrapper class).

Comment: This is a very good point. I should be responsible for making sure that the wrapper works with PHP versions that I check for so that this information is never really needed to be sent to the system.